# Cross platform OpenAL SFX

Tags: android, ios, openal, openal-soft

My engine is built to run and OSX, Windows, Linux, Android and iOS; Im using OpenAL to handle 3d sounds. On OSX and iOS I'm using the default library that comes for the platforms and for the rest Im using OpenAL-soft.

With OpenAL-soft for sound effects there's ALC_EFX that is available but for OSX and iOS I only seems to have access to ALC_ASA (which is Apple specific and seems limited compare to EFX). Is that my only option? There's no way I can have a true cross platform SFX system using OpenAL? Anyways I can use ALC_EFX on iOS/OSX?